# Mensaje no es mostrado al pasar ratón por encima (tooltip) - Typescript

Tags: javascript, html5, angular, typescript, tooltip

Estoy intentando mostrar un mensaje tipo `tooltip` sobre un desplegable (combo), de acuerdo con lo que dice mi función en `typescript`. Si el cliente es Madrid o Barcelona, muestre mensaje **'Los clientes son correctos'**, en caso contrario **'Clientes incorrectos'**. Al pasar por encima del `ng-select` solo me muestra el `tooltip` con el siguiente mensaje: **'tooltip'** pero parece que no realiza la llamada a la función.

**Función `typescript`:**

```
tooltip() {

      var messageTooltip = '';  

      if(this.cliente == 'Madrid' || this.cliente == 'Barcelona') {
        messageTooltip = 'Los clientes son correctos';

      } else {
        messageTooltip = 'Clientes incorrectos';
      }

      return messageTooltip;
  }
```

**Llamada en `html`:**

```
<ng-select ... tooltip="tooltip()">
```

Comment: Te acabo de dar un ejemplo como puedes agregar un tooltip. Te agradezco que marques la respuesta como correcta si te funciona :D

Answer (score 0):

`ng-select` no tiene ningún propiedad soportada llamada `tooltip`. Si deseas agregar un tooltip a las opciones debes de hacer unos de un "custom template" para mostrar la opción y agregar el tooltip.

```
<ng-select 
  [items]="countries"
  [(ngModel)]="selectedCity"
  bindLabel="name"
  bindValue="name"
>
  <ng-template ng-option-tmp let-item="item">
    <div [title]="tooltip()">{{item}}</div>
  </ng-template>
</ng-select>
```

Lo en este caso estoy utilizando la propiedad `title` para mostrar el `tooltip` nativo del navegador. Lo bueno de esta solución es que si deseas utilizar alguna otra librería para mostrar tooltips lo puedes hacer porque tiene acceso al template de la opción.

Te aconsejo evitar utilizar funciones que vayan a ser utilizadas en el HTML para ser interpoladas. Es una mala practica dado que Angular no puede verificar si el valor de esa funcion cambio nada, asi que siempre lo va ejecutar. Lo correcto seria utilizar un ternario o bien un `pipe` para mostrar el texto.

Te dejo un ejemplo funcional
https://stackblitz.com/edit/es-stackoverflow-370432